# Ruby + ImageMagick = RMagick on CentOs

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

```
cat /etc/issue
CentOS release 5.5 (Final)

uname -r
2.6.18-194.11.1.el5

Can't install RMagick 2.13.0. Can't find Magick-config
```

In the log I have found:

> Can't install RMagick 2.13.0. Can't find Magick-config in ...

How I can install RMagick on CentOs ?

Answer (score 1):

This package is in EPEL (Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux), from the Fedora Project. First [configure EPEL on the system](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#howtouse), and then run `yum install ruby-RMagick`.

Answer (score 1):

system package of rmagick install it with specific version. (system ruby version)

native way for your version of ruby would be install with gem.

on ubuntu you would isntall imagemagick and dev libs, here's example in ubuntu:

## Assume you have install ruby via rvm

$ sudo aptitude install imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev 
$ sudo gem install rmagick